# browser caching not disabled after disabling in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, cache

I am having a strange problem in one of my wordpress websites. The problem is that when a webpage is rendered once, editing that page won't be effected afterwards. So no matter how many times you refresh the page(using F5), it will show the old version. But hitting ctrl+f5 will solve the problem and shows the current version of the page. I use no caching plugins. I have disabled browser caching in .htaccess using the code below.

I don't know what else to do to fix this issue. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

EDIT 1:

Http Response Header(F5)

```
Request URL: https://abobargh.ir/compare/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200  (from service worker)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 16 Apr 2021 15:52:30 GMT
link: <https://abobargh.ir/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://abobargh.ir/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/18>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json", <https://abobargh.ir/?p=18>; rel=shortlink
vary: Accept-Encoding
Provisional headers are shown. Disable cache to see full headers.
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36
```

Http Response Header(Ctrl+F5)

```
Request URL: https://abobargh.ir/compare/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 89.39.208.172:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 16 Apr 2021 18:34:35 GMT
expires: Sun, 16 May 2021 18:34:35 GMT
link: <https://abobargh.ir/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
link: <https://abobargh.ir/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/18>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json"
link: <https://abobargh.ir/?p=18>; rel=shortlink
vary: Accept-Encoding
:authority: abobargh.ir
:method: GET
:path: /compare/
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: irk-compare-list=18449%2C19458%2C41925
pragma: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Please add the HTTP response headers to your question.

Comment: (You seem to have posted a _mixture_ of request and response headers?) "Status Code: 200  (from **service worker**)" - You have a _service worker_ running on your site, this is most certainly responsible for the cache-like behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the issue for several days here are the steps that I took to finally overcome the problem:

1. Reset the .htaccess to default values(no luck)
2. Add above values to .htaccess in order to disable leverage browser caching(no luck)
3. Contacted my hosting provider and asked them to disable any potential caching policy on my host(which they replied there are none!)
4. Changed index.php of wordpress to a simple php welcome page in order to determine if it's a server side problem or wordpress problem
5. Cleared the cache of browser and reload the page. Changes were immediately applied!!!
6. Changed index.php to its default wordpress content. Reloaded the page, changes were applied, made another change in the content of the wordpress, Reloaded, and Bingo! No changes were applied. So it was obvious that something in wordpress was messing with the browser cache. So here is what I did:
7. Disabled all the plugins, cleared the browser cache, everything worked perfectly fine. So there is a problem with one of the plugins.
8. Enabled the plugins one by one and re-Run the test.
9. And finally detected the plugin that was failing the whole thing. It is called "PWA for WP" and it is used for turning the website to a web app for mobile. In its settings there were several options for caching html and css and js files. After setting all of the expire times to Zero, everything is working fine!

The problem was that, the plugin was overriding the browser caching settings and even though we disabled the caching in the htaccess, the plugin re-Enabled it again.

So here is the journey I took to overcome this stupid and annoying problem. I shared the steps one-by-one in case it helps someone in the future. Hope it will be useful. Thanks for all the comments.

EDIT:

> MrWhite:
>
> but as you can see from the HTTP response headers, the "plugin" was
> not re-enabling the conventional "browser cache". But this was most
> probably responsive for the "service worker" - JavaScript that runs in
> the browser than is responsible for caching its own content (outside
> of the normal browser cache) typically for "offline" viewing (eg. for
> PWAs).

Comment: "the plugin was overriding the browser caching settings and even though we disabled the caching in the htaccess, the plugin re-Enabled it again." - but as you can see from the HTTP response headers, the "plugin" was not re-enabling the conventional "browser cache". But this was most probably responsive for the "service worker" - JavaScript that runs in the browser than is responsible for caching its own content (outside of the normal browser cache) typically for "offline" viewing (eg. for PWAs).